# SSRS Charts show zero on missing records

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS with Report Builder 3.0 on SQL Server 2014.
A very common thing is showing the turnover of a customer as a bar chart.
But when there is no turnover in a month, the month is missing at all giving a wrong impression of the numbers the chart is representing.

The SQL Query gives me this back:

```
Year,Month,Turnover
2014,12,1000
2015,03,5000
2015,04,10000
2015,05,12000
```

and so on...

[image: Chart with missing values]

As you can see, there are values missing, what I cannot influence.
So it should detect, if there is a missing value and then fill it with zeros.
There must be a elegant way for such a common problem.

There is tons of solutions out there for NULL or Zero Values, but not for missing values.

Comment: I believe you can set the horizontal axis to an axis type of Category. That way all the values will show

Comment: One thing you can do is create a table with year and month columns, include all years and months present in your data, then you can join that table with those used in your query to produce a output with all months for every year even if there is no turnover data for a specific month.

Answer (score 0):

The Chart can't display any data which is not present in the result set.

Anyhow you have to put the dummy data for the missing Year and Month.

You can modify something like below in your current dataset.

```
Select Year,Month, max(Turnover) Turnover
from
(
    Select Year,Month,Turnover from Actualtable
    UNION ALL
    select 2014, 12, 0
    UNION ALL
    Select 2015, 01, 0
    UNION ALL
    Select 2015, 02, 0
    UNION ALL
    Select 2015, 03, 0
    UNION ALL
    Select 2015, 04, 0
    .
    .
    .
    .
) x
group by Year,Month
order by Year,Month
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the horizontal axis properties, set the axis type to scalar. Set the minimum to 1, the maximum to 12, and the interval to 1. You may have to play around with your category groups and series groups.